# Determining R and C for the output filter of the ACS758xCB current sense IC

Tags: filter, noise, current-measurement

I plan to use a current sensor on hexacopter drone (50-150A consumption). The [ACS758xCB datasheet](http://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/ACS758-Datasheet.ashx) gives no information on Rf and Cf. Please advise the values. My application is measuring current my drone takes from a LiPo battery. Sampling rate may be 100-500Hz.

[image: Example schematic from the datasheet]

Here are several tasks I want it for:

1. Protection: I will set up warnings, if something goes
   wrong and current consumption goes abnormal, I will receive alert.
2. Remaining battery charge measurement: as battery will
   discharge I will receive warnings.
3. Total energy consumption: I will record how much I spent in the flight and compare to how much I am charging back to the battery.

Comment: It depends on your sampling rate, as you must realize any spectrum above 1/2 the S&H rate causes aliasing error. If using for Servo control or safe current limiting, then consider the 120kHz BW (typ) of the chip and affects of SNR of the current on feedback control.

Comment: If it has dual purpose then consider signal conditioning for each puurpose with hardware filters for low BW or SW filters for Amp-second accumulation charge useage and high BW  for servo control.

Comment: I want to measure how much current drone uses, and how much mAh is left in the battery. Can you advise?

Comment: How often do you sample the signal? Also, what is the input resistance of your ADC, or if you don't know, then please provide the manufacturer and part number for the processor you are using.

Comment: MCU is STM32F405. How often will it be enough for the purposes I mentioned?

Comment: @RomanSimonyan do you understand Integration ? in hardware and software and the tradeoffs?

Comment: No. Please explain in several words.

Comment: CS datasheet says "120 kHz typical bandwidth". Let's say I will sample at this rate. What I need then?

Comment: Very fast CPU  to add results

Comment: You don't need to sample the current 120000 times per second.  That would be overkill. Your processor would then have to spend a lot of time handling the samples.  Besides, to make use of the 120kHz bandwidth you'd need to sample at least twice as fast.  You need to determine what the shortest significant transients are, then pick a sampling rate high enough to capture those, and design your filter accordingly.

Comment: @JRE can you suggest how to determine what the shortest significant transients are, and how to design the filter accordingly.

Comment: http://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/lipo-fuel-gauge-battery-charge-sensor.html

Comment: You'd probably want to use an oscilloscope on a current shunt to observe the current draw with the drone running.  See what the current draw looks like, find short events that draw a lot of current (you have to decide what is "a lot".) After that, there's a lot information on this site about sampling rates, the nyquist limit, and anti-aliasing filters.

Comment: @Tony, thanks, but my drone uses 150Amps. I know there are some boards available, but I am trying to learn things here and want to assemble a board by myself.

Comment: I am reading many things now and will find some answers soon, but one simple example would really help. Some thing like: "If it uses 60-150Amps I would sample at XkHz and would use Rf YOhms and Cf ZuF". Just as an example.

Comment: You are trying to measure battery draw. So I don't think you want to sample at 120 kHz. I think you want to sample at maybe 100 Hz. I would suggest that you use 10k and 1uF. Or you could sample at 1kHz and then you could use 1k and 1uF.

Comment: The main point is that the low-pass cutoff filter frequency must be much lower than the sample frequency. The RC together form a low-pass filter. The R in the low pass filter must be much smaller than the input resistance of the ADC. I could not find a spec for the input resistance. But the leakage current is around 1uA. So 10k resistor might be kind of large. Also, you are going to need to calibrate the output of your current sensor. Since you are integrating, a small DC offset will accumulate to a very large error very fast.

Comment: @mkeith can you please explain about calibration and error?

Comment: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/battery-management/battery-fuel-gauges.html

Comment: Instead of Ah capacity, which is very inaccurate with varying load profiles.  I would characterize battery ESR @ 4, 3.8, 3.6Vmin and 90%, 50% 10% SOC Then compute SoC from this algorithm using 50 to 100 uΩ ground side flat copper strip Kelvin shunt to sense current with suitable shielding and sense wires at right angles ( a MUST) . You must have a large array of cells and pack ESR well under 1 mΩ because 10% voltage range at 150A load.

Comment: Is this a tank drone?

Comment: Hexacopter with 18inch props and MN5212 motors (30A max current). Takeoff weight 12kg.

Comment: Once you are adquately measuring current, what actions will you take in the knowledge of the current that your are measuring? This might allow others to see a bigger picture and offer better advice.

Comment: First task is protection: I will set up warnings, if something goes wrong and current consumption goes abnormal, I will receive alert. Second, remaining battery charge measurement: as battery will discharge I will receive warnings. Third, total energy consumption: I will record how much I spent in the flight and compare to how much I am charging back to the battery.